# discrepancy in results during conversion from int to bytes and vice versa provides in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-bytearray

I am using `python3.4` in a `venv`.

I am writing a script for a sensor where, after reading a configuration file I need to send an `int` to the serial port in `bytearray`

a snippet of the class function is:

```
def set_sampling(self, type, sampling_us):
        conf_buffer = bytearray([0xfe, 0x06])
        if type not in self.sensor_ids:
            print('Sensor not identified')
        else:
            conf_buffer.append(self.sensor_ids[type])
            conf_buffer.append(0x02)
            if (sampling_us > 0):
                print(sampling_us)
                sampling_bytes = (sampling_us).to_bytes(4, 'little')
                conf_buffer += sampling_bytes
            self.send_frame(conf_buffer)
            self.enable(type)
```

the frame structure is `0xf6 0x06 sensor_id 0x02 sampling_us` where `sampling_us` should be in little-endian format

I have currently `sampling_us` as 1000000 (equals to 1 second)

When I perform the following in the interpreter:

```
>>> (1000000).to_bytes(4, 'little')
```

the result provided is:

```
>>> b'@B\x0f\x00'
```

however I cross-checked with a script for the sensor where the bytes for 1000000 is actually `b'\x40\x42\x0f\x00'`

I reversed the check by performing:

```
 >>> int.from_bytes(b'\x40\x42\x0f\x00', 'little')
 >>> 1000000
```

the correct bytes are in fact `b'\x40\x42\x0f\x00'` as the sensor does not respond if the bytearray sent to it is `b'@B\x0f\x00'`

Why am I getting a discrepancy here? what is it I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do this

```
>>> b'\x40\x42\x0f\x00' == b'@B\x0f\x00'
True
```

you will see there is no discrepancy, you are just looking at two different representations of the same bytestring. In `b'...'` notation, Python's default presentation is that any printable ascii character is shown as that character and not as an `\x` escape.